# Spring- Multi-module not loading the beans - getting exception Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a multimodule spring base application defined as and have used @Import to import the configuration of another module but still, I am getting below exception-

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loyaltyService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'loyalistRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.a.b.loyalty.data.repository.LoyalistRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.a.b.loyalty.data.repository.LoyalistRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**1) Spring-Data-Project**

```
loyalty-data
   main
     java
        com.a.b.loyalty.data.config
        com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity
        com.a.b.loyalty.data.repository
```

> LoyalistRepository.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.data.repository;
@Repository
public interface LoyalistRepository extends JpaRepository<Loyalist, Integer> {
    Loyalist findLoyalistByLoyaltyId(String loyaltyId) ;
}
```

> LoyaltyDataConfiguration.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.data.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.a.b.loyalty.data")
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.a.b.loyalty.data.repository")
//@EntityScan(basePackages ="com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity" )
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoyaltyDataConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.username}")
    private String hikariUserName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.password}")
    private String hikariPassword;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClassName).url(url).username(hikariUserName).password(hikariPassword).build();
    }

}
```

> Loyalist.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOYALTY_DETAILS")
public class Loyalist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "LOYALTY_DETAILS_ID")
    private int loyaltyDetailsId;

    @Column(name = "LOYALTY_ID")
    private String loyaltyId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "DOB")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "IS_NEW")
    private boolean new_;

    @Column(name = "TIER")
    private String gameTier;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

}
```

**2) Spring-Boot-Service**

```
loyalty-service
   main
     java
        com.a.b.loyalty.service
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.config
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.model
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.rest
   test
     java
        com.a.b.loyalty.service
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.config
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.model
        com.a.b.loyalty.service.rest
```

> LoyaltyApplication.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.service;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoyaltyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoyaltyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> LoyaltyServiceConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.a.b.loyalty.service")
@Import({LoyaltyDataConfiguration.class})
public class LoyaltyServiceConfig {

}
```

> LoyaltyService.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.service;


/**
 * Loyalty Service
 */

@Service
public class LoyaltyService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private DroolsLoyaltyProvider droolsLoyaltyProvider;

    @Autowired
    private LoyalistRepository loyalistRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LoyaltyPointRepository loyaltyPointRepository;

//    public LoyaltyService(DroolsLoyaltyProvider droolsLoyaltyProvider, LoyalistRepository loyalistRepository, LoyaltyPointRepository loyaltyPointRepository) {
//        this.droolsLoyaltyProvider = droolsLoyaltyProvider;
//        this.loyalistRepository = loyalistRepository;
//        this.loyaltyPointRepository = loyaltyPointRepository;
//    }

    public LoyaltyResponse calculatePoints(LoyaltyRequest loyaltyRequest) {
        logger.debug(".calculatePoints() Invoked: " + loyaltyRequest);
        LoyaltyProviderRequest loyaltyProviderRequest = LoyaltyProviderRequest.builder().loyalist(PlayerTransformation.toPlayerBO(loyaltyRequest.getLoyalist())).build();
        LoyaltyProviderResponse loyaltyProviderResponse = droolsLoyaltyProvider.execute(loyaltyProviderRequest);
        LoyaltyResponse loyaltyResponse = new LoyaltyResponse();
        loyaltyResponse.setPoints(PointsTransformation.toPointsDO(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints()));
        logger.debug(".calculatePoints() Done");
        return loyaltyResponse;
    }

    /**
     * @return Points
     */

    public LoyaltyResponse retrievePoints(LoyaltyRequest loyaltyRequest) {
        com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity.LoyaltyPoints loyaltyPoints = loyaltyPointRepository.findLoyaltyPointsByLoyaltyIdOrderByModifyDateDesc(loyaltyRequest.getLoyalist().getLoyaltyId());
        LoyaltyResponse loyaltyResponse = new LoyaltyResponse();
        LoyaltyPoints points = new LoyaltyPoints();
        points.setPoints(loyaltyPoints.getTotalEarnPoints());
        return loyaltyResponse;
    }

    public LoyaltyResponse awardPoints(LoyaltyRequest loyaltyRequest) {
        logger.debug(".calculatePoints() Invoked: " + loyaltyRequest);
        LoyaltyProviderRequest loyaltyProviderRequest = LoyaltyProviderRequest.builder().loyalist(PlayerTransformation.toPlayerBO(loyaltyRequest.getLoyalist())).build();
        LoyaltyProviderResponse loyaltyProviderResponse = droolsLoyaltyProvider.execute(loyaltyProviderRequest);

        if (loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints().getEarnedPointForCurrentTxn() > 0) {
            Loyalist loyalist = loyalistRepository.findLoyalistByLoyaltyId(loyaltyProviderRequest.getLoyalist().getLoyaltyId());
            com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity.LoyaltyPoints loyaltyPointsEntity = new com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity.LoyaltyPoints();
            com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity.LoyaltyPoints loyaltyPoints = new com.a.b.loyalty.data.entity.LoyaltyPoints();
            loyaltyPoints.setCurrentPoints(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints().getCurrentPoints() + loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints().getEarnedPointForCurrentTxn());
            loyaltyPoints.setLoyalist(loyalist);
            loyaltyPoints.setLoyaltyEvent("EARN_POINT");
            loyaltyPoints.setLoyaltyId(loyalist.getLoyaltyId());
            loyaltyPoints.setTierDuringPointsEarned(loyalist.getGameTier());
            loyaltyPoints.setTotalEarnPoints(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints().getEarnedPointForCurrentTxn());
            loyaltyPoints.setTransactionDate(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
            loyaltyPointRepository.save(loyaltyPoints);
        }

        LoyaltyResponse loyaltyResponse = new LoyaltyResponse();
        loyaltyResponse.setPoints(PointsTransformation.toPointsDO(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints()));
        logger.debug(".calculatePoints() Done");
        return loyaltyResponse;
    }

}
```

> Test Classes 
>   LoyaltyServiceTest.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.service;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {LoyaltyTestServiceConfig.class})

class LoyaltyServiceTest {

    static private LoyaltyRequest loyaltyRequest;
    static private Loyalist loyalist;


    @InjectMocks
    LoyaltyService loyaltyService;

    @Mock
    DroolsLoyaltyProvider droolsLoyaltyProvider;

    @Mock
    LoyaltyProviderResponse loyaltyProviderResponse;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        loyalist = new Loyalist();
        loyaltyRequest = new LoyaltyRequest();
        loyaltyRequest. setLoyalist(loyalist);
    }

    @Test
    void calculatePointsWhenPlayerIsNew() {
        loyalist.setNew_(true);
        Mockito.when(droolsLoyaltyProvider.execute(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(loyaltyProviderResponse);
        Mockito.when(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints()).thenReturn(LoyaltyPoints.LoyaltyPointsBuilder.aLoyaltyPoints() .withPoints(Mockito.anyInt()).build());
        LoyaltyResponse loyaltyResponse = loyaltyService.calculatePoints(loyaltyRequest);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(loyaltyResponse);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(loyaltyResponse.getPoints().getPoints() > 0);
    }

    @Test
    void calculatePointsWhenPlayerIsNotNew() {
        loyalist.setNew_(false);
        Mockito.when(droolsLoyaltyProvider.execute(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(loyaltyProviderResponse);
        Mockito.when(loyaltyProviderResponse.getPoints()).thenReturn(LoyaltyPoints.LoyaltyPointsBuilder.aLoyaltyPoints() .withPoints(Mockito.anyInt()).build());
        LoyaltyResponse loyaltyResponse = loyaltyService.calculatePoints(loyaltyRequest);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(loyaltyResponse);
        Assertions.assertTrue(loyaltyResponse.getPoints().getPoints() == 0);
    }
}
```

> LoyaltyTestServiceConfig.java

```java
package com.a.b.loyalty.service.config;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class LoyaltyTestServiceConfig extends  LoyaltyServiceConfig {

}
```

Comment: Source code of `LoyaltyService` is missing.

Comment: Added LoyaltyService.java

Comment: If I removed @EnableAutoConfiguration from LoyaltyTestServiceConfig then it's working fine and all the cases are executing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan`

```
package com.a.b.loyalty.service;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repository package name>")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages="<entity package name>")
public class LoyaltyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoyaltyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```